# Complicated SQL constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to prevent data being written using a constraint, but the constraints are complicated.

I have 3 columns:    A  B  C

A record is duplicate if A & B match an existing record, and if A & C match an existing record, but it's valid for B & C to match an existing record, unless A=2.

E.g.
Assume existing records

```
A=1,B=2,C=3
```

If I insert

```
A=1,B=2,C=4
```

I should get an error

If I insert

```
A=1,B=99,C=3
```

I should get an error

If I insert:

```
A=99,B=2,C=3
```

That will succeed.

If I insert:

```
A=2,B=2,C=3
```

I should get an error.

The checks have to be done at INSERT time.  I can't SELECT then INSERT because the data may have changed between the SELECT and the INSERT.

Ideas:

- If I put the logic in a TRIGGER would that work?  I'm not sure if triggers are 100% atomic.
- Would a TRANSACTION work? I don't want to LOCK the table because other processes will be inserting data constantly.
- Could I add one or more constraint(s)?  Is there a way to check the constraints at INSERT time?

Comment: Where is the code with the definition of your trigger?  Also please add the definition (like the CREATE TABLE ... statement) of the table you are using.  (something lik this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/UOmu2LFg) will make your question easier to answer)

Comment: This is a much simplified example, I can't show the real tables.  I'll try DBFIDDLE.

Comment: So the final requirement is that if `A=2` then the combination of `B` & `C` cannot appear *anywhere*, even where `A!=2`??

Comment: If you do `INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C) VALUES(2,2,3);` and then `INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C) VALUES(12,2,3);` is that ok?

Comment: @Larnu 2,2,3 should fail, but 12,2,3 should succeed.

Comment: Why would `INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C) VALUES(2,2,3);` if there are no other rows with `2`, `3` for `B` and `C`? It's unique at that point, so what's causing it to fail?

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Yes, 2,2,3 would succeed the first time but fail the second time.

Comment: @Neil (2,2,3) and (12,2,3) are not a valid combination, since you say that "if A & C match an existing record". The question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simple combinations of uniqueness for columns `A` & `B` and `A` & `C` you can solve this with a unique index or unique constraint. For the latter problem, however, this isn't so easy.

I use a `TRIGGER` here, and check to see if a matching row, with the same values of `B` & `C` is found (where the ID differs, as otherwise the row will match to itself) and where either the inserted row has a value of `2` for `A` or the existing row does. If a match is found, an error is `THROW`n, causing the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` to fail.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int IDENTITY,
                            A int NOT NULL,
                            B int NOT NULL,
                            C int NOT NULL);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_YourTable_AB ON dbo.YourTable (A,B);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_YourTable_AC ON dbo.YourTable (A,C);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_chk_YourTable_BC_A2 ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM inserted i
                    JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON i.B = YT.B
                                         AND i.C = YT.C
                                         AND i.ID != YT.ID
                WHERE 2 IN (i.A,YT.A))
        THROW 54697, N'The check trigger ''trg_chk_YourTable_BC_A2'' on table ''dbo.YourTable'' failed. Cannot insert duplicate row on columns ''B'' and ''C'' where at least one row has the value of ''2''.',16;
END;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C)
VALUES(1,2,3);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C)
VALUES(1,2,4); --Fails
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C)
VALUES(1,99,3); --Fails
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C)
VALUES(99,2,3); --Works
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C)
VALUES(2,2,3); --Fails
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C)
VALUES(4,5,6); --Works

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C)
VALUES(5,5,6); --Works
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C)
VALUES(2,5,6); --Fails
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C)
VALUES(3,7,9); --Works
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A,B,C)
VALUES(2,7,9); --Fails

GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Obviously, you may well wish to change the error number and message, but I wrote something reasonable.
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aT8jTwSs)

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I think you can use unique filtered indexes.

1. UNIQUE : A,B --always
2. UNIQUE : A,C --always
3. UNIQUE B,C WHERE A==2

Answer (score -1):

I would try using Common Table Expressions and add a where clause on the insert statement.  If the insert returned zero rows updated, then consider the insert failed?

```
-- Assuming A and B do not permit NULLs
; WITH cteAB AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT a,b FROM YourTable
)
, cteBC AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT b,c FROM YourTable
)
INSERT  YourTable ( a, b )
SELECT NewA, NewB
FROM YourTable yt 
LEFT JOIN cteAB ab ON ab.a=NewA AND ab.b=NewB
LEFT JOIN cteBC bc ON bc.a=NewA AND bc.b=NewB
WHERE ( ab.a IS NULL AND bc.a IS NULL )
    OR NewA=2
```